# tic-tac-toe ways to check if player has won

Tags: python, processing, tic-tac-toe

I'm still new to OOP programming and writing compact code so there probably something I'm overlooking, I'm trying to figure out a way to check for vertical wins and diagonal wins in tic-tac-toe, I have horizontal already.

---

If possible is there a way to incorporate the other two ways into something like what I already have?

```
#creates the gameboard that stores if spaces are open or not
game_board = [ [0,0,0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0,] ]
#0 = open space
#1 = O
#2 = X

#check for winners horizontaly
def find_winner():
    # y represents the y axis
    for y in range(3):
        if game_board[y][0] == game_board[y][1] == game_board[y][2] != 0:
            #returns if the X or 0 has won
            return game_board[y][0] 
    #returns 0 if no-one has won   
    return 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add more `if` statements like this:

```
game_board = [ [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0,] ]

def find_winner():
    for y in range(3):
        if game_board[y][0] == game_board[y][1] == game_board[y][2] != 0: # Check horizontal
            return game_board[y][0]
        if : # Check vertical
            return game_board[0][y]
    if game_board[0][0] == game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][2] != 0 or game_board[0][2] == game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][0] != 0: # Check diagonal
        return game_board[1][1]
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help, these are the two functions for vertical and diagonal checking

```
# Checks for vertical row 
def win(game_board, player): 
    for x in range(len(game_board)): 
        win = True

        for y in range(len(game_board)): 
            if game_board[y][x] != player: 
                win = False
                continue

        if win == True: 
            return(win) 
    return(win) 

# Checks diagonal win 
def diag_win(game_board, player): 
    win = True
    y = 0
    for x in range(len(game_board)): 
        if game_board[x, x] != player: 
            win = False
    win = True
    if win: 
        for x in range(len(game_board)): 
            y = len(game_board) - 1 - x 
            if game_board[x, y] != player: 
                win = False
    return win
```

Feel free to comment if you have some queries or suggestions. For the above function, the players are selected at random. It is a good practice to use functions

Answer (score 1):

### Only 3 List Comprehensions

#### All Wins and Positions

```py
game_board = [ [1, 0, 1],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0] ]

# Horizontals
h = [str(i+1) + ' Row' for i, v in enumerate(game_board) if sum(v) == 3]

# Verticals
v = [str(i+1) + ' Col' for i in range(3) if sum([j[i] for j in game_board]) == 3]

# Diagonals
d = [['Left Diag', '','Right Diag'][i+1] for i in [-1, 1] if sum([game_board[0][1+i], game_board[1][1]], game_board[2][1-i]) == 3]

if any([h,v,d]):
    print('You won on:', h, v, d)
else:
    print('No win yet')
```